# angular 10 ng-select get value from DOM

Tags: angular, selenium

I have on an angular 10 project some views where I use ng-select to display (and get) some data.

The QA team has some tests that rely on element id and DOM value - built for simple select elements. On a simple select, we can use the DOM element and read the value property in order to get the selected value.

Question: Is any way to retrieve the selected value from an ng-select component from DOM, in a similar way we get it from html select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an `ng-select` with bindLabel as `name` , you can use the following to select the value of ng-select:

```
const selectValue = document.querySelector('[bindLabel="name"]').getElementsByClassName('ng-value')[0].innerText;
console.log(selectValue);
```

You can test this using the stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select

Just open the devtools, go to console and paste the above query.